Differential magnetic susceptibility v.s. magnetic susceptibility?
For a given material which has the M-H curve looks like the following figure:

When I extract the magnetic susceptibility of the material, should I use the ratio between M and H, $\chi_m=\frac{M}{H}$, or should I use the differential susceptibility, $\chi_m=\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}$?
More specifically, at H>2T, is $\chi$ for this material zero or nonzero?
Thanks!

The right definition is $$\chi$=\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}.$$ Usually you are interested in the value at $H=0$. As it seems linear, taking the derivative is equal to $H/M$. If you do not have enough points you might have a problem at $\chi$ for $H=2$ T, but as you want $H>2$ T, you are fine. From the picture it seems that $\chi>0$ but small in that region.

Dear Mauricio, thank you for your answer. So to make sure I understand you correctly: the relation \chi=M/H is only valid near H=0 where the curve is linear. In all the other fields, we should always use the differential magnetic susceptibility. So in the figure I show, the susceptibility should be roughly constant  for |H|<2T, and becomes (almost) zero at |H|>2T, is that correct?

@physstudent11 exactly

Now I understand it. Thank you!
